# How to call Kotlin method with more than one similar signature with lambda?

Tags: java, kotlin, higher-order-functions, overload-resolution

I am using some code from this library: https://github.com/Netflix-Skunkworks/rewrite

When I call one of its methods, I encounter an IDE error:

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

The target method has two similar signatures:

```
data class CompilationUnit(...){

    fun refactor() = Refactor(this)

    fun refactor(ops: Refactor.() -> Unit): Refactor {
        val r = refactor()
        ops(r)
        return r
    }

    fun refactor(ops: Consumer<Refactor>): Refactor {
        val r = refactor()
        ops.accept(r)
        return r
    }
}
```

The calling code in Kotlin:

```
val unit: CompilationUnit =...
unit.refactor{ tx ->
   doSomeThing()
}
```

And this call with lambda is OK in Java:

```
CompilationUnit unit = ....
unit.refactor(tx -> {
    doSomeThing()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the calling code in Kotlin: you are passing a lambda with one argument `{ tx -> doSomething() }`, but a lambda with receiver and no arguments is expected there.

Compare: `(Refactor) -> Unit` is the [type for a function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types) with one argument, while `Refactor.() -> Unit` means a [function with receiver](http://Refactor.()%20-%3E%20Unit), which takes no arguments and instead is passed a receiver (`this`) of type `Refactor`. These types are sometimes interchangeable, but lambdas are not converted between them implicitly.

So, you can call `refactor` it as follows:

```
val unit: CompilationUnit = ...
unit.refactor {
   doSomeThing() // this code can also work with `this` of type `Refactor`
}
```

Alternatively, to call the overload with `Consumer<Refactor>`, you can explicitly specify that:

```
unit.refactor(Consumer { tx -> doSomething() })
```

Implicit [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) is, apparently, not available because there are several overloads with functional parameters.